# Error sending test email gitbucket

Tags: gitbucket

The email settings was setup using a gmail account and when testing it the error below is returned.

> [Error] org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to
>   the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:587

The settings are host: smtp.gmail.com, port:587 and STARTTLS/SSL Enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try a combination of enabling STARTTLS and disabling SSL.

Comment: Gmail blocks sending email from unreliable apps in default by security reason. Have you changed a setting of your Gmail account to allow that?